# WDT Reset Issue during Sleep on PIC12F675 - Need Long Wakeup Interval

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I'm working on a project using a **PIC12F675** microcontroller. My goal is to read voltage using the built-in ADC on GPIO1, and based on the measurement result, I want to turn ON an LED for a few seconds. After this, I intend to put the microcontroller to sleep using the **SLEEP()** macro and repeat the measurement process after approximately one hour (a longer duration, such as 2 hours, would also be acceptable).

My problem is that the watchdog timer (**WDT**) can only be set to approximately **2.3 seconds**. Even when I tried to enclose the **SLEEP()** macro in a loop, the WDT automatically resets the microcontroller after just 2.3 seconds. I'm wondering if there's any other way to wake up the microcontroller from sleep after a longer period without using an external trigger. Unfortunately, I can't use an external trigger for this purpose. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve the desired wakeup interval without encountering the WDT reset issue?

**Here's my code:**

```c
#include <xc.h>

// Configuration bits
#pragma config FOSC = INTRCIO   // Internal oscillator
#pragma config WDTE = ON        // Watchdog Timer enabled
#pragma config PWRTE = OFF      // Power-up Timer disabled
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // MCLR pin function is digital I/O
#pragma config BOREN = ON       // Brown-out Reset enabled
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code protection disabled

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000     // Internal oscillator frequency for delay functions

void main() {
    TRISIO = 0b00000010;      // GP1 (ADC input) is an input, GP0 (LED output) is an output
    
    ANSEL = 0b00000010;       // Set GP1 as analog input
    
    while (1) {
        // Perform ADC measurement
        ADCON0 = 0b00000001;  // Select GP1 as ADC input
        __delay_us(20);       // Delay for ADC charging time
        GO_nDONE = 1;         // Start ADC conversion
        while (GO_nDONE);     // Wait for conversion to complete
        
        // Read ADC result and control LED
        uint16_t adcResult = ((ADRESH << 8) + ADRESL);
        
        if (adcResult > 512) {
            GP0 = 1;  // Turn ON LED
            __delay_ms(2000);  // Keep LED ON for 2 seconds
            GP0 = 0;  // Turn OFF LED
        }
        
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3600; i++) {  // Loop for approximately 1 hour
            SLEEP();  // Put microcontroller to sleep using WDT
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're likely to find a better solution than what you already have.  The PIC's energy usage should be pretty minimal if it's just waking up once every 2.3 seconds and running a handful of instructions, right?

Comment: You could wake up your controller with an RTC. Maybe use an external one or change to a controller with a build in RTC.

Answer (score 4):

Because it is not possible to change the RC oscillator frequency of the watchdog by other means than the prescaler, we can't slow it down further than what you did.

The description of the sleep instruction for the PIC12F675 is as follows (emphasis mine) :

> The power-down STATUS bit,
> PD is cleared. Time-out STATUS
> bit, TO is set. **Watchdog Timer**
> and its prescaler are **cleared**.
> The processor is put into SLEEP
> mode with the oscillator stopped.

The description of the watchdog (point 9.6) :

> During normal
> operation, a WDT time-out generates a device RESET.
> If the device is in SLEEP mode, a WDT time-out
> causes the device to wake-up and continue with normal
> operation

Given that, the code you provided should work, and seems to be the only reasonable way to have a long sleep period. Note that in your sleep loop the MCU is running for only around 10 us each time it wakes up (wake up delay and a few instructions), that's a minuscule fraction of the time it spends in sleep mode, it is negligible.

More importantly, the ADC still consumes power when the MCU is in sleep mode, shut it down before going in sleep mode (ADON of the ADCON0 register) and enable it back again after.

Answer (score -1):

I'm doing something similar. You should set WDT timeout to 2.3 and check your current draw and see if your SLEEP() is actually stopping the Fclk clock and resetting the WDT.

Comment: Not an answer to the question asked.  Possibly should be a comment.  The sleep state of the MCU is well defined, why would you have to "_see if your SLEEP() is actually stopping the Fclk_"?  Moreover SLEEP is a macro provided by xc.h not _"your SLEEP"_.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34983973)